# Запоминание класса у элемента

Tags: php, jquery

Есть список

```
<ul>
 <li class="sort">1</li>
 <li class="sort">2</li>
 <li class="sort">3</li>
</ul>


<a href="1.php">link</a>
```

По клику по конкретному li добавляется класс red.
Если пользователь переходит по ссылке и возвращается назад, то класс red не запоминается. Как сделать так чтобы класс red сохранялся у li даже при переходе на другую ссылку?

Comment: В кукисы записать позицию и при выводе учесть или аяксом отослать на сервер информацию об отмеченном элементе

Comment: не силён в куках, как будет это всё выглядеть, подскажите пожалста

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie тут все просто описано для js, а для php можно воспользоватся суперглобальным массивом $_COOKIE

Answer (score 2):

Если Вам необходимо реализовать сортировку, а точнее если вам нужно «запомнить» значение для одного или небольшого числа блоков, то можете воспользоваться cookie/ Тогда код на js будет:

```
NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

function setCookie(name, value, options) { // функция установки cookie
  options = options || {};

  var expires = options.expires;

  if (typeof expires == "number" && expires) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + expires * 1000);
    expires = options.expires = d;
  }
  if (expires && expires.toUTCString) {
    options.expires = expires.toUTCString();
  }

  value = encodeURIComponent(value);

  var updatedCookie = name + "=" + value;

  for (var propName in options) {
    updatedCookie += "; " + propName;
    var propValue = options[propName];
    if (propValue !== true) {
      updatedCookie += "=" + propValue;
    }
  }

  document.cookie = updatedCookie;
}
/*Обработка нажатия на блок*/
var divs = table.querySelectorAll(".sort");
divs.forEach(function(el, iNum){ 
    el.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        addActiveClassToCookie(el.innerText, iNum);
    });
});

function addActiveClassToCookie(data, num){ // сохранение значений в cookie
    setCookie("sortActiveValue", data, {
        expires : 60*60*24*365, // ставим куку на год
        domain : window.location.host // ставим доступной для текущего домена
    });
    setCookie("sortActiveNum", num, {
        expires : 60*60*24*365
    });
}
```

В php Вы можете получить эти значения и вывести соответствующий класс:

```
$sortActiveValue = $_COOKIE["sortActiveValue"];
$sortActiveNum = $_COOKIE["sortActiveNum"];
```

Но не забудьте проверить что данные, которые в куке безопасны.

**Самое главное**

Если Вам необходимо для большого числа классов записывать данные (приходилось делать такое пару раз), то Вам нужно хранить данные в браузере из-за того что cookie передаются в каждом запросе к серверу и могут значительно «утяжелить» его.